# Supremum of expectation of absolute value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider that $$X(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{4},\\ \frac{5x}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{4},\end{cases}$$
where $x\in\left<0,1\right>$ is fix and $$X(y)=\begin{cases} \frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{4},\\ \frac{5y}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{4},\end{cases}$$
where $y\in\left<0,1\right>$ is fix.

I wolud like to find out if $$\sup\limits_{x\neq y}\left[\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{\left|X(x)-X(y)\right|}{|x-y|}\right)\right]<1.$$

I have made some editting, i.e.
$$\sup\limits_{x\neq y}\left[\frac{1}{|x-y|}\mathrm{E}\left(\left|X(x)-X(y)\right|\right)\right]<1.$$

But I do not have idea how to copmute $\mathrm{E}\left(\left|X(x)-X(y)\right|\right)$. I have been trying some ways but then I think I cannot compute $\sup$ easily.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what's the probability that $X(x)=\frac{5x}6$ **and** $X(y)=\frac{y^2}2+\frac12$?

Comment: $X(x)$ and $X(y)$ are idependent, it means that probaility is $\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}$ (I think). That also means that $P(X(x)-X(y)=\frac{5x}{6}-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Correct. You have 4 cases, with probabilities $1/16$, $3/16$, $3/16$, $9/16$. Now calculate the expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $$X(x)-X(y)=\begin{cases} (\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2})-(\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}), &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4},\\ \frac{5x}{6}-\frac{5y}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4},\\ \frac{5x}{6}-(\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}), &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4},\\ (\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2})-\frac{5y}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\end{cases}$$

$$X(x)-X(y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2-y^2}{2}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{16},\\ \frac{5(x-y)}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{9}{16},\\ \frac{5x-3y^2-3}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{16},\\ \frac{3x^2+3-5y}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{16}\end{cases}$$

$$|X(x)-X(y)|=\begin{cases} \frac{|x^2-y^2|}{2}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{16},\\ \frac{5\cdot |x-y|}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{9}{16},\\ \frac{|5x-3y^2-3|}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{16},\\ \frac{|3x^2+3-5y|}{6}, &\text{ with prob. } \frac{3}{16}\end{cases}$$

$$E(|X(x)-X(y)|)=\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{16}+\frac{5\cdot |x-y|}{6}\cdot\frac{9}{16}+\frac{|5x-3y^2-3|}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{16}+\frac{|3x^2+3-5y|}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{16}$$

$$E(|X(x)-X(y)|)=\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{32}+\frac{15\cdot |x-y|}{32}+\frac{|5x-3y^2-3|}{32}+\frac{|3x^2+3-5y|}{32}$$

$$\frac{E(|X(x)-X(y)|)}{|x-y|}=\frac{x+y}{32}+\frac{15}{32}+\frac{|5x-3y^2-3|}{32\cdot|x-y|}+\frac{|3x^2+3-5y|}{32\cdot|x-y|}$$

This expression is not limited. Take $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $y=x+\delta$, $0<\delta<\frac{1}{4}$ then

$$\frac{E(|X(x)-X(y)|)}{|x-y|}=\frac{7}{16}+\frac{\delta}{8}+\frac{5}{64\delta}$$

At $\delta\to 0$ this expression tends to infinity. So supremum is infinite.